# user defined function for shiny dashboard downloadHandler?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny dashboard that has multiple buttons that trigger an instance of the `downloadHandler` function.  I am downloading both images and csv files (don't ask why).  I have the `downloadHandler` capabilities working, but I have to create a separate instance for each file to be downloaded.  Does anyone have an example of a user defined function that facilitates the `downloadHandler`?

I'd really like to have one instance of the `downloadHandler`code, not the multiple instances I have now.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip folder to store your csv files and images and download it at once:

```
output$Download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function(){
    paste("Download","zip",sep=".")
  },
  content = function(con){
    tmpdir <- tempdir()
    setwd(tempdir())
    files <- c() #List your files 

    zip(zipfile=con, files = files)
  },
  contentType = "application/zip"
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mal_a,
This is essentially what I have in my application.  Is there a way to wrap this code in a function, something like:
function_x <- function(outputspec, filespec){
  outputspec <- downloadHandler...
}
With the filespec setting the particulars of the file to be downloaded.
That way I wouldn't need a downloadHandler block for each file I need to download.
Any ideas How to do this?
TIA